# Disable click event and call it on blur event of select dropdown using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have multi select dropdown of countries.On change event of this select dropdown,the ajax form submit is triggered.

```
  <select name='country[]' id='country' multiple='multiple'>
      <option value='1'>USA</option>
      <option value='2'>India</option>
      <option value='3'>Japan</option>
  </select>
```

I want to disable on change event ajax form submit and call the ajax submit on blur event of select dropdown.

How can I do that using Jquery?

Here is the on change jquery code

```
  $('#country').change(function() {
    //ajax form submit 
    $.post("form_save.php", $("#form").serialize());
  });
```

Comment: post your js code.

Comment: You can disable an event by using jquery off method like $('#country'). off('click') ; and for onblur ajax call iy will be $('#country'). blur (function() {//your ajax code}) ;

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "change" Event

```
$('#country').change(function() {
  //Do your ajax stuff
});
```

Comment: I dont want to submit form on change..that is I am already doing

Comment: Then you would have to use .blur instead of .change

Answer (score 1):

Can you try following logic:

```
var hasCountryChanged = false; //declare global variable
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#country').change(function() {
        hasCountryChanged = true; //set the flag as value has been changed
    });

    $( "#country" ).blur(function() {
        // do ajax call only if value is changed; otherwise don't
        if(hasCountryChanged){
            hasCountryChanged = false; //reset the flag
            //ajax form submit 
            $.post("form_save.php", $("#form").serialize());
        }
    });
});
```